# Make Visual Studio 2015 a Visual Basic IDE

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Is there a way I can launch Visual Studio 2015 in a single language mode, e.g. just Visual Basic. So that I can create separate launch shortcuts for each language and technology e.g. shortcut for Visual Basic, Visual C#, ASP.NET etc.?

**Note:** Launching from that shortcut should only show project templates for that language and not show all the installed templates.

[image: Visual Studio New Project Dialog]

Here are **Devenv Command Line Switches** but I am not sure whether there is such option.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7.aspx

Comment: What is the benefit of that?

Comment: To be more focused and possibly speed up Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure the IDE to the settings you want and export the settings from the `Tools -> Import and Export Settings...` menu. Then use the [`/ResetSettings SettingsFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241273.aspx) commandline switch to load the exported settings from each of your shortcuts.